# Mongodb Aggregation with $group, Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sum, grouping, aggregate

If I don't have any value,
console always print out undefined error...

Collection Name: post

```
_id,
id,
name,
mobile,
price,
create_at


db.posts.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        created_at: {$gte: start, $lt: end}, 
        mobile: p_mobile,
        id:p_id
    }
},
{
    $group: { _id : null, sum : { $sum: "$price" } }
}
],function(err, result){ 
    if (err) throws err
    if(result){
        console.dir(result);
        console.log("object sum : " + result[0].sum);
        return res.send(result);
    } 
});
```

Once I have a normal document It's fine.
However It prints out "uncaughtException TypeError: Cannot read property 'sum' of undefined" when the conditions do not match...

Why does the node not recognize the sum field?

Comment: Always make sure there are match conditions in place to filter out error values (undefined, null, " ", [ ]) etc. And then change your logic to print/execute only when `result` has values (check whether array is empty).

Comment: Can you show show us an example document from the posts collection? Also what MongoDB version are you running the aggregation from?

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem specifically with the sum field? For example, if you print out the entirety of 'result[0]', what does that give you?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project and here is how I solved it.

```
const rentalsCount = await Rental.estimatedDocumentCount();

let totalFee = 0;
if (rentalsCount > 0) 
   totalFee = await getTotalRevenue();

const rentals = await Rental.find().sort('-dateOut');

res.send({ totalFee, rentals });
```

The result will look like this if there is no document

```
{
"totalFee": 0,
"rentals": []
}
```

I hope that will help someone.